# Auto deploy from GitHub to IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, github, deployment, httphandler

For Asp.net generic handlers.
I am using code in this repository:
https://github.com/tshwangq/IISDeploy

For last 3 days I am trying To achieve auto deploy to IIS 8.5 but I don't not understand step 4 in readme.md

"config IIS, make sure the PostReceiveHook.ashx can be visit from internet."

I have added postreceivehook.ashx in root folder but I cannot access it from Internet however I can access all other files

Do I need to change IIS settings?
Please help!!

Comment: Hi I need to to exactly that, I have a repo in Github that I need to publish into a QA server using IIS 8.5. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use kudu or more simple solution is to clone repo on prod and only fetch no push so that means don't change code on server directly